# Windows Community Toolkit export/backport MasterDetailsView from repo

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, master-detail, windows-community-toolkit

[v5.0.0](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/releases/tag/v5.0.0) of the [Windows Community Toolkit](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit) dropped support for the Creators Update (15063).
Now I want to manually backport the [MasterDetailsView XAML Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/masterdetailsview).

I've already included the following files from the [Windows Community Toolkit](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit)  [v5.0.0](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/releases/tag/v5.0.0) [MasterDetailsView XAML Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/masterdetailsview) source code in my project:

- [BackButtonBehavior.cs](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/MasterDetailsView/BackButtonBehavior.cs)
- [MasterDetailsView.cs](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/MasterDetailsView/MasterDetailsView.cs)
- [MasterDetailsView.Events.cs](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/MasterDetailsView/MasterDetailsView.Events.cs)
- [MasterDetailsView.Properties.cs](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/MasterDetailsView/MasterDetailsView.Properties.cs)
- [MasterDetailsView.xaml](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/MasterDetailsView/MasterDetailsView.xaml)
- [MasterDetailsViewState.cs](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/MasterDetailsView/MasterDetailsViewState.cs)
- [VisualTree.cs](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/Extensions/Tree/VisualTree.cs)

If I now create one with the following XAML code:

```xml
xmlns:masterdetailsview1="using:ProjectName.Toolkit.MasterDetailsView"
<masterdetailsview1:MasterDetailsView x:Name="chats_mdv"
                                      Grid.Row="1"
                                      Background="Transparent"
                                      DetailsTemplate="{StaticResource DetailsTemplate}"
                                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MasterTemplate}"
                                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.CHATS_ACV}"
                                      MasterPaneBackground="{StaticResource AppBackgroundAcrylicElementBrush}"
                                      NoSelectionContentTemplate="{StaticResource NoSelectionTemplate}"
                                      SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The result of the code above is a [MasterDetailsView XAML Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/masterdetailsview) without any behavior.
I can't interact with it. It's stuck in the master pane only mode.
It does not react if I click on any master item to view it.

**Which files do I have to include in my project for this to work?**

Comment: Are there any messages in the output window while debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The result of the code above is a MasterDetailsView XAML Control without any behavior. I can't interact with it. It's stuck in the master pane only mode. It does not react if I click on any master item to view it.

I followed your steps to make a code sample to test. I can reproduce your issue. The problem was that it cannot find the `MasterDetalsView.xaml` resource file when the `OnApplyTemplate()` method get called.

To solve this issue, open your project's App.xaml and add the following resource in it.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MasterDetailsView/MasterDetailsView.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

My project's directory structure like the following:

[image]

You need to change the source by your own project's directory structure.

Comment: Well I'm at the moment on v4.0.0 but I want to user the v5.0.0 MaterDetailsView because it has some important bug fixes in it for me. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: @COM8 If you want to use v5.0.0, you would have to switch your project's target to 16299 or higher.

Comment: I **do not** want to use the complete v5.0.0 build I just want to backport the MaterDetailsView to run on 15063. So I need to know which files include code,styles,animations, behavior, ... of the MaterDetailsView so I can manually backport them.